# Is there a way to print the definition of a function in python

Tags: python, function, definition

I was wondering if there is a way to print what the funciton definition?

so if I want to do something like:

```
def hello():
    print 'hello'

some_function_to_show_definition(hello())
```

and the output should be:

```
print 'hello'
```

Just messing around in python and I was just wondering :)

Comment: you might want to check [https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/313df3800a05f4ef72fb7bf4509ed699926cb1b2/IPython/core/oinspect.py]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inspect` is the way to go:

```
In [8]: def foo():
   ...:     print 'hello'
   ...:     

In [9]: import inspect

In [10]: inspect.getsourcelines(foo)
Out[10]: ([u'def foo():\n', u"    print 'hello'\n"], 1)
```

Comment: You just beat me to it! Just a note, this does not work in `CPython` interactive mode.

Comment: Yep, it's probably not a good idea if a program relies on such kind of low level introspection.